# Folder structure for Backbone without RequireJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

### The goal

Elaborate a folder structure to Backbone in Rails 4 without RequireJS.

### The problem

I'm not creative or even a *good-standards-guy* to folder structures, and I really need to know how to compose a good one for my application.

I'm playing on Rails 4 and getting trouble with Asset Pipeline + RequireJS, then I gave it up of use it but I didn't found any guides that clarify a good folder way for me.

Then I'm here to ask: **someone can help me with a good folder structure?**

Answer (score 1):

You can look at a few projects to get some ideas :

- from my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction): https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction
- from my [Marionette & RequireJS book](https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette): https://github.com/davidsulc/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette
- Derick Bailey's example app: https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail
- And of course there's http://www.backbonerails.com covering how to develop Marionette apps with Rails